# Can't solve this. Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm following this ZF2 tutorial but got this error

> `Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter`

I tried everything, I used solutions from similiar posts but it still dont works.

module.php

```
    <?php namespace Album;

 use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface;
 use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;
 use Album\Model\Album;
 use Album\Model\AlbumTable;
 use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
 use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;



 class Module implements AutoloaderProviderInterface, ConfigProviderInterface
 {
     public function getAutoloaderConfig()
     {
         return array(
             'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
                 __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
             ),
             'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                 'namespaces' => array(
                     __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                 ),
             ),
         );
     }

     public function getConfig()
     {
         return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
     }
    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'Album\Model\AlbumTable' =>  function($sm) {
                    $tableGateway = $sm->get('AlbumTableGateway');
                    $table = new AlbumTable($tableGateway);
                    return $table;
                },
                'AlbumTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                    $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                    $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Album());
                    return new TableGateway('album', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
                },
            ),
        );
    }

 }
```

global.php

```
<?php
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'driver'         => 'Pdo',
        'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=logowanie1;host=localhost:3306',
        'driver_options' => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'
                    => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Code looks okay. What you have in global.php is the important bit. Where is the global.php file located in your project?

Comment: It is located in config/autoload